# How do i read two CSV files, then merge their data, and write to one CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, append, filereader

To clarify, I have 2 CSV files I want to read.

**First** CSV has the following headers: ['ISO3', 'Languages', 'Country Name'].

**Second** CSV has the following headers: ['ISO3', 'Area', 'Country Name']

I want to write to a new CSV file with the following headers (and their corresponding values obviously), so like: ['ISO3', 'Area', 'Languages', 'Country Name']. Basically, I want to merge the 2 CSVs, without having the duplication of ISO3 and Country Name.

Right now, i am reading both CSVs and then I am able to successfully write the 'Area' to the original written CSV which contains only ['ISO3', 'Languages', 'Country Name'].

**However, the formatting is off.**

```
import csv

filePath = '/file/path/shortlist_languages.csv'


fp_write = input("Enter fp for writing new CSV (do not include .csv extension): ")

country_data_fields =[]

with open(filePath) as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:

        country_data_fields.append({
            'Languages': row['Languages'],
            'Country Name': row['Country Name'],
            'ISO3': row['ISO3']
        })

with open('/file/path/shortlist_area.csv') as file_t:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_t)

    for row in reader:
        country_data_fields.append({
            'Area': row['Area'],
        })

with open(fp_write+'country_data_table.csv', 'w',
          newline='') as country_data_fields_csv:
    fieldnames = ['Languages', 'Country Name', 'ISO3', 'Area']
    csv_dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(country_data_fields_csv, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_dict_writer.writeheader()

    for data in country_data_fields:
        csv_dict_writer.writerow(data)
```

The CSV result looks like the below:

```
Languages,Country Name,ISO3,Area
Albanian,Albania,ALB,
Arabic,Algeria,DZA,
Catalan,Andorra,AND,
Portuguese,Angola,AGO,
English,Antigua and Barbuda,ATG,
,,,28748
,,,2381741
,,,468
,,,1246700
,,,442
```

I want the "Area" values to be nicely lined up with the others though, so how?

Comment: You can use `dict.update()` to combine two dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're identifying each record by the 'ISO3' key? Use a dict instead of a list, using the 'ISO3' value as a key.

In the first loop instead of `.append` just set the dict value with the key, in the second loop get the existing record dict for that key, set `['Area']` to the `row['Area']` value, and it should update properly. Something like this (not tested):

```
for row in reader:
    iso3 = row['ISO3']
    country_record = country_data_fields[iso3]
    country_record['Area'] = row['Area']
```

Modify the final loop to iterate through the dict instead of a list.

Comment: In the second loop, how do i get the existing record for that key? And how  would the final loop iteration look like? Are you able to update with code example?

Comment: You might want to learn more about how to use `dict` types in Python, but meanwhile I edited the answer with example code.